# In DBeaver how to find Current largest fact table number of rows and size sql query

Tags: sql

I'm using Dbeaver software and trying to write an sql query statement to find the Current largest fact table number of rows and size of the table.

How to write an sql query

My Table name is : transactionsale ( It is a fact table)

regards,
Prabhu

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Current largest fact table number of rows sql script -------  Select count(0) from transactionsale..... this query giving me less number of rows